# Where to start debugging, when you get the "Activity is not responding, Force Close, Wait"?

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, thread-safety

I have worked on a simple application. It application includes diffrent levels that can be solved by placing some components inside a canvas, dragging them to the right place and so on.

The application is working fine, but when trying it on my HTC Desire 2.2, I *sometimes* get the warning message:

**Sorry:
Activity xxxxx is not respoding.
*Force Close - Wait***

If I press the wait-button and let it be for some seconds (up to ~30 sec sometimes), then it runs without any problems. I don´t know where I should start debugging the code, since it happenes only once in a while.

I have read the stuff in google developer site and it was just mostly very general stuff that did not really help.

any ideas?

since, I was not able to debug the problem myself, I am going to post the most important parts of the application. Please check and let me know If I need to post more classes.

```
//Evrything else
Bitmap bitmap;
GraphicObject.Coordinates coords;
for (GraphicObject graphic : _graphics) {
    bitmap = graphic.getGraphic();
    coords = graphic.getCoordinates();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, coords.getX(), coords.getY(), null);
}
// draw current graphic at last...
if (_currentGraphic != null) {
    bitmap = _currentGraphic.getGraphic();
    coords = _currentGraphic.getCoordinates();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, coords.getX(), coords.getY(), null);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android has a relatively good profiler support built in.
When you know the place where this ADNR will show up (e.g. with in one method of your activity, you can put that block in a tracing block:

```
Debug.startMethodTracing("xyz");
<your code goes here>
Debug.stopMethodTracing()
```

This will upon activation write a trace file to /sdcard/xyz.trace

You can later (after such a ADNR occurred) obtain it via

```
adb pull /sdcard/xyz.trace
```

and analyze it via

```
traceview xyz.trace
```

Within the traceview screen, you see the method with its called methods and you can then see the timings.
See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html

Comment: thanks, will try this when I get home. It seems like the way to go.

Comment: I put the two methods from above inside the UIthread and the code crashes as soon as the application pops up. any ideas?

Comment: @Alborz. No I think the log should have an information what is wrong here. Perhaps no sdcard mounted? Or no permissions in your app.xml to write to the sdcard?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, not setting SD permission was the problem. I have been able to see the traceview.

I think the problem is in the UIThread when I draw the components over and over again. Is there a way to fasten this snippet... (see edit)

Comment: @Alborz  Traceview display should give you a clear indication where most of the time is spent and so on. Especially the table at the bottom lists the interesting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing network connections on the main thread? Or Time.sleep()'s. Or extremely long running calculations?

Something in your app's main thread is taking more than 5 (or is it 10?) seconds to complete.

Comment: @Felmarri, I have no "Network connections" or Time.sleep(). 
I place the graphical objects that user places on the screen inside an array and then I use a Thread to go though all the element in that array and paint them.
Where can I read more about this 5/10 sec you have mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating the 30 second sleep on the main thread, if so, the application will be unresponsive for about 30 seconds and the android system will show force close dialog will show up after 5 second. Try creating the 30 second pause and action on a new thread. Check android developers site for more information about threads.

And if you don't know where to start debugging, check your logcat log and search for errors or warnings. Check this -> http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html for some information about logcat.

Hope that helped. :) Good luck.

Edit: Then i think that you should put the functions that the wait button performs inside a new thread, so that the application becomes responsive instantly and the child thread remains unresponsive, which doesnt matter.

Edit Again: oh, i get it now, sorry for the misunderstanding, so you are not sure where the problem is, try searching for any network connections, sleep/pauses in your code. Oh, and connect your phone to your computer, run the app by pressing F5 and try to search for warnings or errors in logcat just when the force close box opens. And try to copy the logcat log and send it to me, and ill check whats wrong.

Comment: @Kaushal Subedi: I don´t have any thread.sleep in my application, I was explaining that when I press the "Wait-button" it takes almost 30-45 sec before the application is responsive again.

Comment: The wait-button is Android standard, it has nothing to do with my application. I think you have misundrestood me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new `StrictMode` to detect what is causing your UI thread to hang.
Take a look at [this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html).

It is only available for GingerBread (API level 9), so you can just test it on the emulator, perform the necessary cleanup, and then remove the StrictMode code